# How do I conditionally configure Docker settings with Bazel's rules_docker?

Tags: bazel

I am using Bazel's `rules_docker` package to build some container images. When using Bazel locally, I'd like it to communicate with the docker daemon via Unix socket. When running in CI, I'd like to use TCP.

I understand how to use `docker_toolchain_configure` to set the host flag, but I can't figure out how to conditionally set the value in CI.

Comment: Does "set the value in CI" mean "set the value in Bazel"? What have you tried and what doesn't function?

Comment: It means configure Bazel to use Docker over TCP when running in CI. Bazel doesn't pass the typical environment variables like `DOCKER_HOST` down, so you must use `docker_toolchain_configure` in your `WORKSPACE` file in order to configure your Docker options. The issue is that you can only have a single configuration as far as I can tell, there's no way to use different settings in different environments.

Comment: Any luck here? Im trying to accomplish a similar thing. And so far it looks like you cannot use `select` config values while evaluating the workspace perhaps?

Comment: I was overthinking this, you can simply supply an action env var like so `build --action_env=DOCKER_HOST`

Comment: @WinstonRIley that doesn't actually work. `rules_docker` doesn't pass variables supplied via `--action_env` to docker.

Comment: it's working for me. I have a bazelrc file we use in CI with the above. and we are not customizing the `docker_toolchain_configure`. Happy to explain more if you are interested. (and locally docker uses a socket) (on bazel 4.0.0 rules docker @ 0.19.0)